# DIsplay products list based on tag

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.5.1.
Is it possible to display list of products that have tags? Example products with tag "RM50"

Comment: @Sankar can you guide me thru ?

Comment: Please update your question with more details and also let us know what have you tried.

Comment: baseurl.com/index.php?route=product/search&tag=tagname - lists your products with that particular tagname.

Answer (score 0):

In opencart by default if you pass the tag name to the search controller it will list the products that matches the tag.

Ex.

```
   www.yoursite.com/index.php?route=product/search&tag=RM50
```

This url will list the products for tag `RM50`

replace `www.yoursite.com` with your domain name